# How to add Pushpin Onclick Event?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing

I am using the below code to disaply multiple pushpins from an XML file. I would like to know how I setup an tap event for each pushpin that will pass a value

```
    foreach (var root in Transitresults)
    {
        var accentBrush = (Brush)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];

        var pin = new Pushpin
        {
            Location = new GeoCoordinate
                {
                    Latitude = root.Lat,
                    Longitude = root.Lon
                },
            Background = accentBrush,
            Content = root.Name
        };

        BusStopLayer.AddChild(pin, pin.Location);

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have forget to register the event handler - I don't see pin.Click += ...

Comment: @KarelFrajtak That click event was for the wrong code. I removed it.  How would I add an onclick even for this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is pretty close, try this:-

```
    foreach (var root in Transitresults)
    {
        var accentBrush = (Brush)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];

        var pin = new Pushpin
        {
            Location = new GeoCoordinate
                {
                    Latitude = root.Lat,
                    Longitude = root.Lon
                },
            Background = accentBrush,
            Content = root.Name,
            Tag = root
        };
        pin.MouseLeftButtonUp += BusStop_MouseLeftButtonUp;


        BusStopLayer.AddChild(pin, pin.Location);

    }
}

void BusStop_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var root =  ((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag as BusStop;
    if (root != null)
    {
        // You now have the original object from which the pushpin was created to derive your
        // required response.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it doesn't like MouseLeftButtonUp += BusStop_MouseLeftButtonUp is that correct for WP7? INvalid initializer member declarer

Comment: you can't register event handler in initalization, but it is the point - event is registered.

Comment: @KarelFrajtak Sorry, can you explain what you mean please?

Comment: First - your code is not registering any event handler, second - you can only initalize properties in initializer block (the code wrapped with { and } right after 'new PushPin')

Comment: @KarelFrajtak Yes, because I'm not sure how to  register an event handler for pushpin taps or press. Thats why I am asking the question.

Comment: @KarelFrajtak is correct.  You can only perform plain assignments to properties in an object initializer.  Modified my code to correct.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Great, thanks for that. Once last thing, the Type BusStop in the `Tag as BusStop` is saying its undefined, shoud this be sometehing else?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones I just moved that tag as BusStop and it works fine. How would I pass a variable through this event? I want to pass this var from each one `Content = root.Name,`

Comment: @Rhys: One of the dangers of `var` is overuse.  If in your initial `foreach` you had not used `var` but instead specified the type that `Transitresults` is a list of I would of used that type name instead of `BusStop`.  So I just guessed assuming you'd see for yourself the need to replace this made up name with the type you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.maps.pushpin_events%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for PushPin events you can see that Tap event is available and so you can register a handler:

```
pin.Tap += args => { /* do what you want to do */ };
```

Comment: But note that `Tap` is only available on 7.1.  Pre-mango API does not have `Tap`.

Comment: Googling more -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744574/how-should-i-handle-click-events-on-pushpins-in-my-bing-maps-control-for-wp7